# MS-SQL: Select top 10 Records which are entered atleast 30 seconds beore?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select top 10 records from a table which are entered in DB atleast 30 seconds before.

I have a column called DateReceived in this table.

Thanks
Prabath

Comment: What is your DB ?

Comment: AFAIK newer SQL Server versions support ANSI SQL's `FETCH FIRST`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
SELECT  DateReceived
FROM yourtable  
WHERE DateReceived  <= DATEADD(SECOND,-10, SYSDATETIME());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM _table AS t
WHERE t.DateReceived BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(ss, -30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY t.DateReceived DESC;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.